# Magento product image is not visible in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

Well. I am working on my first magento web site.I am using `magento V1.9.2.4` with `luxury theme V1.2.4` Its all working fine but Product image.(I am working on localhost xampp )

I uploaded Images trough Catalog -> manage product -> myProduct -> Images -> upload image. Then selected the image Base image, Small image, Thumbnail in the image option.

As it wasnt visible by this so i changed `php_value memory_limit 512M` in `.htaccess` file in my root. this method is not worked.

As I am working on windows i tried to give full permissions to the media folder in the root. still nothing

I also checked if Image attribute have scope global.

I tried using almost all image sizes viz 100X100 200X200 400X400... but still its not working.

what i have to do in this case?

If it helps when i upload 'x' number of images in my back-end. Magento displays 'x' number of product images thumbnails(dummy image) in my front-end product landing page

Admin page of product
[image]

Product Landing Page
[image]

.phtml in folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\design\frontend\mgstheme\luxury\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml`

```
<?php

/**
 * Product media data template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media
 */
?>
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

    $panelHelper = $this->helper('mpanel');
    $size = $panelHelper->convertRatioToSize();
?>
<div class="entry hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="image-media" id="main-images">
        <?php
            $_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->
            init($_product, 'image')->resize($size['width'], $size['height']).'" 
            alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" 
            title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" 
            class="img-responsive"/>';
        ?>
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image'); ?>

        <div class="magnifier">
            <div class="buttons tooltips">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($size['width'], $size['height']) ?>" class="sf" title="" data-gal="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mobile-media owl-carousel hidden-lg hidden-md">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): $i++; ?>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="entry<?php if($i==1): ?> first<?php endif ?><?php if($i%3==0): ?> last<?php endif ?>">
                <div class="image-media">
                    <img data-main-image-src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="magnifier">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>" class="sf" title="" data-gal="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    jQuery(".mobile-media").owlCarousel ({
        rtl:<?php echo $panelHelper->rightToLeftOwl(); ?> ,
        items: 1,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        dots: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
        navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"],
        responsive:{
            0 : {items: 1},
            480 : {items: 1},
            768 : {items: 1},
            980 : {items: 1},
            1200 : {items: 1}
        }
    });
</script>
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="thumbnails clearfix hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="thubmbnail">
            <div class="thubmbnail-row">
                <div id="services" class="services owl-carousel thumbnails-carousel">
                    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): $i++; ?>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="entry<?php if($i==1): ?> first<?php endif ?><?php if($i%3==0): ?> last<?php endif ?>">
                                <div class="image-media">
                                    <img data-main-image-src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="magnifier">
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>" class="sf" title="" data-gal="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        jQuery("#services").owlCarousel ({
            rtl:<?php echo $panelHelper->rightToLeftOwl(); ?> ,
        items: 1,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        dots: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
        navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"],
        responsive:{
            0 : {items: 1},
            480 : {items: 2},
            768 : {items: 2},
            980 : {items: 3},
            1200 : {items: 3}
        }
        });
        jQuery('a[data-gal]').each(function () {
            jQuery(this).attr('rel', jQuery(this).data('gal'));
        });
        jQuery("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({slideshow: false, overlay_gallery: false, social_tools: false, deeplinking: false, theme: 'light_rounded'});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".services .item .image-media img").click(function(){
                jQuery("#main-images img").attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
                jQuery("#main-images .magnifier a").attr("href", jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Edit::**
I Narrow Down the problem

in here `resize` function if I give manual height and width It shows image fine. what is the problem with it now?

like this `resize($size[100], $size[100]);`

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
```

Comment: screen shot of that product view page in admin and the phtml file please

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Check what `$panelHelper->convertRatioToSize()` method rerturns

Comment: Help me with it '(

Comment: `print_r($panelHelper->convertRatioToSize())`; die;

Comment: `Array ( [width] => 0 [height] => 0 )` this is the output

Comment: That's it, you need to set the width  and height

Comment: if you can tell me where that function gets value from?

Comment: There should be a module with helpers defined as "mpanel". The easiest way to find this is search for `convertRatioToSize()` in your `local` and `community` directories

Comment: This is not a default method, you need to paste the content of that method here

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: Is there a file in your local directory called `MGS/Mpanel/Helper/Data.php`?

Comment: Yes `C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\code\local\MGS\Mpanel\Helper\data.php`

Comment: paste the method convertRatioToSize() here

Comment: Well done!! put that as answer... in that function `convertRatioToSize()`  had `NULL` value i entered some value in it. Somehow its working now! Thank you

Comment: posted that as asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the images are creating without any issues when you hard code the width and height in phtml, You need to check what is returned by the method `$panelHelper->convertRatioToSize();` and need to make sure it is not returning `null`.

To check the method, your need to go to:
`app\code\local\MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data.p‌​hp`